# How can I seperate a maths formula into array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
"formula=today+Buy+yes-(25*2)-3"
```

I need an array:

```
["formula","=","today","+","Buy","+","yes","-","(","25","*","2",")","-","3"]
```

How can I separate the formula like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve this you can use a regular expression which searches for alphabetic groups, such as `formula`, `A`, `B` etc, the mathematical operators and the digits. The `match()` method will return you an array of each distinct part found in the original string.

```js
let inputs = [
  'formula=A+B+C-(25*2)-3',
  'formula=today+Buy+yes-(25*2)-3'
].forEach(s => {
  let matches = s.match(/[a-z]+|[=+()*-]|\d+/gi);
  console.log(matches);
});
```

Thanks to @JaromandaX for improving the regex!

Comment: you're over escaping :p `/[a-z]+|[=+()*-]|\d+/gi` - no need to escape any of those, even the `-` if it's last

Comment: You're right, clearly rusty on my regex :)

Comment: @May in that case can you please add more examples to the question showing the various inputs and their expected outputs. Or start a new question showing them all, as the problem outlined in the OP has been solved above.

Comment: yes, I see, you are right.. I am adding more examples..

Comment: Given your edit the above still works. I've edited the answer to show that working too

Comment: the only problem ı saw yet is = "that code changes "_" with ","

Comment: [a-z-_] soved my problem, I start to understand Regex thans to you...@RoryMcCrossan